# Keras: Is there any way to "pop()" the top layers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In Keras there is a feature called pop() that lets you remove the bottom layer of a model. Is there any way to remove the top layer of a model?

I have a fully saved pre-trained Variational Autoencoder and am trying to only load the decoder (the bottom four layers).

I am using Keras with a Tensorflow backend.

Comment: Have you tried `pop(0)`?

Answer (score 1):

Keras pop() removes the last (aka top) layer, not the bottom one.

I suggest you use model.summary() to print out the list of layers and than subsequently use pop() until only the necessary layers are left.

Comment: Good Answer. One could add that the bottom/top layer might not even properly defined due to possible multiple inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 0):

pop(0) works for me

```
from keras.applications import vgg16
vgg = vgg16.VGG16(include_top=False, input_shape=(604,604,3))
vgg.summary()
vgg.layers.pop(0)
vgg.summary()
vgg.layers.pop()
vgg.summary()
```